# Spark SQL - createDataFrame wrong struct schema

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

When trying to create a DataFrame with Spark SQL by passing it a list of Rows like so:

```py
some_data = [{'some-column': [{'timestamp': 1353534535353, 'strVal': 'some-string'}]},
             {'some-column': [{'timestamp': 1353534535354, 'strVal': 'another-string'}]}]
spark.createDataFrame([Row(**d) for d in some_data]).printSchema()
```

The resulting DataFrame's schema is:

```
root
 |--  some-column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

This schema is wrong, as `strVal` column is of `string` type (and indeed collecting on this DataFrame would result in `nulls` on this column).

I'd expect for the schema to be an `Array` of appropriate `Structs` - inferred with a bit of Python reflection on the types of values.
Why is this not the case?
Is there anything I can do besides providing the schema explicitly in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the structure doesn't encode what you mean. As explained in the [SQL guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) Python `dict` is mapped to `MapType`.

To work with structures you should use nested `Rows` ([`namedtuples` are preferred in general, but require valid name identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37147450/10465355)):

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

Outer = Row("some-column")
Inner = Row("timestamp", "strVal")

spark.createDataFrame([
    Outer([Inner(1353534535353, 'some-string')]),
    Outer([Inner(1353534535354, 'another-string')])
]).printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- some-column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- strVal: string (nullable = true)
```

With the structure you have at the moment, the scheme outcome could be achieved with intermediate JSON:

```py
import json

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(some_data).map(json.dumps)).printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- some-column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- strVal: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
```

or explicit schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField(
    "some-column", ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("timestamp", LongType()), 
        StructField("strVal", StringType())])
))])

spark.createDataFrame(some_data, schema)
```

although the last method might not be fully robust.

Comment: Thanks, the JSON trick is exactly what i was hoping for.
Why isn't this the default behavior? e.g. for `spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)` - cant the schema be inferred by doing this very same trick?

Comment: Schema is inferred according to the linked specification so it couldn't be, without making a whole process full of special cases.