# how to specify different types of DataFrames in python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Let's say that I have a Pyspark DataFrame which I consider is "Users".
Then I have another one which I consider "Cars".

Now lets say that I have a function which return a dataframe of type "Cars".

Usually I see code like this:

```
def get_cars() -> Dataframe:
    pass
```

However "Dataframe" is not very expressive....is too generic. So, is it possible to specify something like this using alias or similar?:

```
def get_data() -> Cars: 
    pass
```

Comment: im not asking how to install pandas or how to create a dataframe

Comment: Why do you think what you are asking is not possible within pandas or pyspark?

Comment: oh nono, im asking how can be done, no that is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) :

> [`builtins.type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) now supports subscripting (`[]`). See [*PEP 585*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) and Generic Alias Type.
>
> Source : [[*docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)]

```
Cars = type[pd.DataFrame]

def get_data() -> Cars:
    ...
    
print(Cars) # type[pandas.core.frame.DataFrame]
```

---

From the comments :

> .. this type hint **won't say anything about the columns** that this Cars Dataframe contain.

In this case, you may be tempted to use [`pandera`](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) ([*which also supports PySpark SQL*](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyspark_sql.html)):

```
#pip install pandera
import pandera as pa
                          
Cars = pa.DataFrameSchema({
    "Model": pa.Column(pa.String),
    "Year": pa.Column(pa.Int),
})

def get_cars() -> Cars :
    return pd.DataFrame({
        "Model": ["Lambo", "Porshe", "Mustang"],
        "Year": [2023, 2000, 2010],
    })
```

Output :

```
print(Cars.dtypes) # {'Model': DataType(str), 'Year': DataType(int64)}
```

If you need to validate the schema, you can try this :

```
df = get_cars()

try:
    Cars.validate(df.astype({"Year": "float"}))
except pa.errors.SchemaError as e:
    print(f"WRONG SCHEMA: {e}")

# WRONG SCHEMA: expected series 'Year' to have type int64, got float64
```

Comment: It would help, however this type hint won't say anything about the columns that this Cars Dataframe contain.

Comment: I updated the answer to address that.

Comment: Pandera seems the way to go. Thanks a million

Comment: This answer is better than mine, thanks for showing this library. I still keep my answer up for people who face the problem in a more general sense, not specific to dataframes, or cant use the library.

Answer (score 1):

Make empty subclasses of DataFrame (override nothing). That way, you can use "Users" anywhere a DataFrame is expected but you have the option to specify one of your methods should only work with "Users"

```
class Users(DataFrame):
    pass
```

This technique is sometimes known as "Microtypes" and is often applied to Strings with special meaning in applications where many domain-objects need to be modeled as strings though they are not interchangeable.

Some consider this an antipattern, because someone unfamiliar with the code will not know what 'Users' is. So decide based on many factors such as team size and IDE-availability whether this bit of type-safety makes your code better or worse.

Comment: I like it, is really simple. However this typee hint won't say anything about the columns that this Users Dataframe contain.

Comment: What you can do is add a function that takes a dataframe, validates it against your Users-rules and either return a Users-object or throw an error. This technique is not perfect though, since dataframes are mutable.

Comment: Think of this whole thing as a measure to reduce your risk of mixing up the order of arguments to a function, not to make everything completely statically safe. For that you would have to override al the Dataframe-methods to enforce that the validations stay true and to return the correct type (Users not DataFrame). And that will definitely do more harm than good.

Comment: @FranciscoAlbert : Using namedtuple instead of generic Row could be better solution. I have provided answer which points to this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I misunderstood your question earlier. Anyways, what you are asking for is really a Scala's `case class` equivalent in pyspark. Luckily there is something like this which is supported at the row level.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49949762/3238085

1. A real equivalent of named product type, is a namedtuple.
2. Has well defined shape and can be reliably used for structural pattern matching.
3. Provide highly optimized representation. Unlike Row objects, tuple don't use **dict** and carry field names with each instance. As a result there are can be order of magnitude faster to initialize
4. Last but not least namedtuples are properly supported in Spark SQL.

It should be clear that Row is a very poor substitute for an actual product type, and should be avoided unless enforced by Spark API.

It should be also clear that pyspark.sql.Row is not intended to be a replacement of a case class when you consider that, it is direct equivalent of org.apache.spark.sql.Row - type which is pretty far from an actual product, and behaves like Seq[Any] (depending on a subclass, with names added). Both Python and Scala implementations were introduced as an useful, albeit awkward interface between external code and internal Spark SQL representation.